# Sync MediaElement to Slider in Windows Store App

Tags: windows, xaml, slider, mediaelement, windows-8.1

Im developing an app like media player to  Windows Store using c#. I use C# But I have a problem .

I want to sync MediaElement to slider. For examle the music in the mediaelement and music is playing. I want to see the position of music in the slide bar. For example if music in the 30th , Sliderbar's value is 30.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a very similar question already. Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212853/link-media-element-on-wpf-with-label-and-slider/21322260#21322260) and let me know if that's what you were looking for! If you need more details, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

A msdn tutorial including the implementation of a slider control is provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh986967.aspx). Hope this helps.